# Same origin with 2 cumul ggplot

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, series

When I plot 2 data frame in the same graph, I can't get the same origin
Here a sample of my data :

```
spec_sum <- data.frame(x = c("2015-01-08","2015-01-13","2015-01-14","2015-01-15","2015-01-15","2015-01-19","2015-01-19","2015-01-21","2015-01-21","2015-01-27"),y = c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

odtgen_sum <- data.frame(x = c("2015-01-12","2015-01-14","2015-01-15","2015-01-26","2015-01-27","2015-01-29","2015-01-30","2015-01-30","2015-02-04","2015-02-04"),y=c(1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1))
```

Here my ggplot code :

```
library(reshape)
newData <- melt(list(spec_sum = spec_sum, odtgen_sum = odtgen_sum),  
  id.vars = "x")

#Specify colour vector
cols <- c("blue", "red", "green", "orange")

ggplot(newData, aes(x, cumsum(value), colour = L1)) + 
  geom_line() +  xlab("Date") + ylab("Nb depeches dev") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols) + theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.justification=c(0,0), legend.position=c(0.8,0))
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb61e.jpg)

Comment: What should  the result look like?

Comment: My problem is I have an offset between my 2 lines and I don't know how remove this offset.

Comment: Normally, the 2 lines should begin approximatively at the same level on the count axis (cumul) but I got an offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess** it's because `cumsum` does not aggregate per group in your example. Try calculating it beforehand:

```
# create toy data
set.seed(1123)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(f=gl(2, n, lab=letters[1:2]), 
                 x=rep(1:n, 2), 
                 y=rbinom(2*n, 1, .5))
# add cumulative sum
df$y_cum <- ave(df$y, df$f, FUN=cumsum)
# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y_cum, color=f)) + geom_line()
```

** *You did not provide a reproducible example.*